# Curly braces not working in arrow function (javascript) in React whereas parentheses do

Tags: reactjs, syntax

This works ->
[image: parentheses]

However if i switch the () with {} it doesn't render anything, such as:
[image]

Im quite confused because i thought an arrow function is defined with curly braces if it has multiple statements such as here:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the second case with `{}` you haven't **return** an ui component which is why it isn't working, where as in `()` it treats the contents as the return block.

so to use `{}` you need:

```
{this.state.users.map((person, idx) => {
    return <Contact 
        key={idx}
        id={idx}
        name={person.name}
        email={person.email}
        phone={person.phone}
        onDelete={this.handleDelete}
/>
})}
```

Comment: wait so thats why we also use () for the return of render? i was so confused about it aswell, thanks for the clarification. I didnt know that was a JSX thing i thought it was avanilla javascript thing.

Comment: you use () after return for big components which can go multiline and putting them in () results in better linting but it's not necessary. in the map function if you don't provide {} it treats the statement after the arrow as the return which is why () works

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your `Contact` element if you use Curly braces. That is JSX syntax.

```
{your_array.map((item) => {
  return <Contact />
}))
```

Comment: If we are not returning anything then we dont need to use {} brackets. If we are just rendering something then () will work fine.